# Redirect to .php file via form action does not work (beginners Questio..)

Tags: php, forms, post

Im not getting redirected to the debuggerPHP.php file. It works in XAMP but it doesnt work on my website. It might have to do with the fact that it can't find the .php file.. but i don't know what the path should be like.

the structure of the directory is:
www -> files of mainwebsite -> **files of subdomain**

The .html and .php file are in the same directory. they are in a subdomain called: subdomain.maindomain.com & www.subdomain.maindomain.com

this is my debuggerPHP.php code:

```
<?php
    echo 'test';
?>
```

this is my app.html code:

```
<form action="debuggerPHP.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="your email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
```

Please help me

Comment: try write to action full url of debuggerPHP.php file

Comment: is direct access to 'debuggerPHP.php' from browser shows you a 'test'-message?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Ivan i have tried http://subdomain.maindomain.com/maindir/subdir/debuggerPHP.php and http://www.subdomain.maindomain.com/maindir/subdir/debuggerPHP.php and http://www.subdomain.maindomain.com/subdir/debuggerPHP.php and http://www.subdomain.maindomain.com/debuggerPHP.php but with no succes :(

Comment: @Wizard no it doesn't, it only does when i write it like: maindomain.com/subdomain/debuggerPHP.php. but when i use that in the form action it still doens't work

Comment: @Fred-ii- this can't possible be a php error because the only script in the php file is an echo. Or am i missing something? thanks for the help though

Comment: @Samvanbeastlo , I can suggest that you have some misconfiguration on your production server. You said your domain has subdomain, but you can't reach your php-files by accessing them through this subdomain-name. May be web-server sets wrong environments for php-workers. Do you have just a host with cpanel or you can access (and do that) via root-ssh? Your code has no issues (for this particular case), it's something else.

Comment: @Wizard I only have a cpanel so if this is the case then i think i have to ask the admin for help. Thanks i will send him an email!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a header to your debuggerPHP.php

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
  echo 'test';
?>
```

1) From a Browser enter address `http://maindomain.com/debuggerPHP.php`

What happens?

If you use `<form action="debuggerPHP.php" method="post">`

Make sure debuggerPHP.php is in the same server directory as your HTML page.

The will always work if debuggerPHP.php is in the root (e.g public_html) directory.

```
<form action="http://maindomain.com/debuggerPHP.php" method="post">
```

Then submit the form from your HTML page.

What happens?

### Update:

Based on what you said your form should be:

```
<form action="http://maindomain.com/subdomain/debuggerPHP.php" method="post">
```

Comment: 1)when i type http://maindomain/debuggerPHP.php the browser will get nothing but when i goto http://maindomain/subdomain/debuggerPHP.php the php page and it displays the echo. 

2) my debuggerPHP.php is in the same directory as my app.html page. they are both in the subdomain dir, think that also is a root dir? 

3) when i now submit the form it does redirect to a different page but it shows a white page with the text www.maindomain.com and not 'test' like it should echo if it was directed to the .php page. Think we're making progress haha i really apreciate all help !

Comment: Thanks for your help you made my day! it works :D i've accepted your awnser!